# Call CKEditor by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I need to call multiple instances of CKEditor automatically...actually I use the function:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1');
```

Where "editor1" is the id name of the div where I want show my CKEditor.

I'm using jQuery to automate this process and I need to use the "class" tag instead the id.

In particular i have this html:

```
<div class="CKEditor">
    <div class="text">
            mytext
    </div>

    <p style="text-align:center" class="buttons">
        <input type="button" value="edit" class="button_edit">
        <input type="button" value="preview" class="button_preview" style="display:none">
    </p>

    <div class="editor" >
    </div>

</div>
```

and this jQuery script:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('.CKEditor').each(function()
    {
        var __main = $(this);
        var __buttons = __main.children('.buttons');
        var __text = __main.children(".text");
        var editor;

        __buttons.children('.button_edit').click(function()
        { 
            __text.hide();
            if (editor) return;

            editor = CKEDITOR.replace("editor");
            editor.setData(__text.html());

            if(editor)
            { 
                __buttons.children('.button_edit').hide(); 
                __buttons.children('.button_preview').show(); 
            }
        });

        __buttons.children('.button_preview').click(function()
        {
            __text.show();
            __text.html(editor.getData());

            if ( !editor ) return;

            editor.destroy();
            editor = null;
            __buttons.children('.button_edit').show(); 
            __buttons.children('.button_preview').hide(); 
            __main.children("#editor").html("");
        });
    });
});
```

Is it possible without modify the source of CKEDITOR?

---

**EDIT**

I found the solution:

1)  The html become:

```
<div class="editor" id="edt1"></div>
```

2) In the JQuery:

```
var __editorName = __main.children('.editor').attr('id');
```

and i call CKEditor with:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace(__editorName);
```

=) =)

Answer (score 16):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replaceClass = 'ckeditor';
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" name="content"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
   <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80"  name="content"></textarea>
  </div>    
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the posted snippet does not work. This answer needs updation

Answer (score 9):

There is already a class replacer built into CKEditor. Any textarea with the class `ckeditor` applied will have the editor applied automatically **without initialisation**.

The code is in **ckeditor.js** and uses `CKEDITOR.replaceClass="ckeditor";`

---

**Initialise by class** *(no extra JavaScript required)*

Add Class `ckeditor` to textarea

**HTML**

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

**.NET**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" CssClass="ckeditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

---

**Custom Class initialisation**

If you wish to use your own class you can simply overwrite the class with your own initialisation **after** ckeditor.js

Use:

```
CKEDITOR.replaceClass="MyClass";
```

Answer (score 8):

Using replaceAll.

[replace textarea using class](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#method-replaceAll)

in the page:

```
<textarea class="myClassName"></textarea>
```

in the JS code

```
CKEDITOR.replaceAll( 'myClassName' );
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible now, check this: 
http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/standard/ckeditor/samples/old/replacebyclass.html

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use function like this :

```
function loadEditor(id){
    var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
    if(instance){
        CKEDITOR.destroy(instance);
    }
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(id);
}
```

I use it with lots of dynamic config, and I am sure it can be nicely changed to suit your needs. Have a play and let us know what you come with!

As you can see I am using ids anyway, but can't see a problem with using classes

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replaceClass = 'ckeditor';
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" name="content"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
   <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80"  name="content"></textarea>
  </div>    
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimalist example that illustrates using the `ckeditor` class on text areas, based on a stripped down version of http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/standard/ckeditor/samples/old/replacebyclass.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="something" class="ckeditor">
    &lt;p&gt; Hello world! &lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>
```

In my testing I found that the `<textarea>` tag needed to have the `ckeditor` class, and it needed to have an `id` or `name` field present.

Answer (score 0):

...which is a bit strange, because the **Replace by Class** sample contains the following code:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
```

*And it works perfectly fine*.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to instantiate multiple ckeditor4 instances is using the ckeditor-jquery adapter.

Then only

```
$( 'textarea.ckeditor' ).ckeditor();
```

is enough to have multiple ckeditor instances.