# Generating CKEDITOR does not work on for loop statement using javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

It is possible to create a ckeditor using for loop statement in javascript? Everytime I generate a ckeditor within textarea, the ckeditor is not show up. Any idea. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 for(var index = 1; index <= 4; index++ ){
  str += '<textarea class="ckeditor" name="answer[]"></textarea>';
 }
</script>
```

Sample Image: [image]

Comment: bro, were you able to solve this issue? I've been stuck with it for a couple of hours already :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [ckeditor5 readme](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/master/README.md), it appears that you need to have the HTML textarea(s) already inserted and then call the create method for each textarea, passing its id as the parameter. I pulled this from the readme:

In your HTML page add an element that CKEditor should replace:

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
```

Load the classic editor build (you can choose between CDN, npm and zip downloads):

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/<version>/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Call the ClassicEditor.create() method:

```
<script> 
   ClassicEditor .create(
      document.querySelector( '#editor' )
   ) .catch( error => { console.error( error ); } );
</script>
```

You’re ready to go!

So, following those instructions, you should be able to call create for each textarea, in your loop, as long as it's been added to the document before you call create().

Edit:  If you really want to use an older version of ckeditor, it looks like a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021825/call-ckeditor-by-class) mentions using `.replace()` or `.replaceClass()`

Comment: I tried your answer but this is not working. ID on textarea are not good idea because you generate a textarea using for loop with the unique ID so that I tried to use a class instead of ID on textarea but doesn't work. By the way thank you for responding

Comment: @YadYoung The selected answer to the following question recommends using `appendChild` so that your new elements are added to the DOM, and a few other good suggestions to make sure that you can access your dynamically added elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902803/getelementbyid-where-element-is-dynamically-created-at-runtime